# A mystifying grid

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Puzzle Name: TAKE TWOs

[image]

Text Only:

```
L   R   D   N   S   D   Q
D   B   L   B   T   E   U
N   T   F   Y   P   K   U
A   L   M   C   D   O   N
Z   C   F   D   B   S   I
E   I   H   N   T   U   F
L   O   R   G   C   E   L
K   H   I   E   A   K   U
T   S   L   O   U   N   L
```

Solve this puzzle, and you'll discover a location that could be associated with the phrase "Take Two".

Hint 1:

> There's a reason why the puzzle's name ISN'T 'Take Two'.

Hint 2:

> The relative positions of the letters is a red herring (i.e. This puzzle is still solvable even if the entire grid is completely scrambled).

Comment: Most certainly _knowledge_ tag is applicable for this.

Comment: I don't agree. To my knowledge, you can solve this without googling, and I have tested it out with people who were able to solve it without external knowledge. The final sentence is more of a teaser to the solution - you can safely ignore it and still figure the answer.

Comment: I can't help but to see "BL", "BS" and think of BioShock and Borderlands from Take-Two. Seems to require [tag:knowledge] though, and I can't seem to make anything else work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking the letters appear an even number of times we end up with

> AEEHRTT (we count the letters appearing 4 times as 2 * 2 times)

which gives the word

> THEATER

that we can associate with the phrase "Take two" which give

> [Take Two theatre](https://www.taketwotheatre.com)

Comment: you got it, although the location isn't specific. The association is with the place being somewhere where you can watch movies, and movie directors yelling that phrase when shooting movies. As mentioned, the association is meant to be loose, and not needed to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like

> answer is FILM STUDIO (as we can see that pairs of letters are available in the grid as FI, LM, ST, UD, IO) and it is that place where generally for a re-take that word - Take two is used.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but that is not the solution I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It can be

> EARTH / THRAE (taken letters in pairs i.e. occur 2 or 4 times in grid)

OR

> E.T. (Extra Terrestrial) taken letters those occur four times

Take Two:

> may be only two letters

Comment: you are on the right track, but are you sure you took the right letters?

Comment: ok edited but not sure yet

Comment: I think you could get a better word if you took the letters that occur four times twice.

Comment: @M Oehm i also think about it that it could be extra-terrestrial but no idea about take two. I have no knowledge:(

Comment: M Oehm's got the gist! Just follow his thought process and you'll probably get the answer. You don't need external knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

After counting the repeated letters:

> L, U, N, D where the most repeated

The place is

> LUND
> It is a city in the province of Scania, southern Sweden.

Another place might be:

> Dunet
> Dunet is a commune in the Indre department in central France